# how detect in which form is responsed json string from server and how parse and use it?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a c# program that sends some requests to server and receives some response string in json form.

server sends response in one of these json forms :
[image]

this method executes after receiving response from server :

```
struct param
{
   public String url, postjson;
   public Object res;
}

void sendtoserverCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e2 = (RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)e;
    param response = (param)e2.Result;

    Object res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.res.ToStrin  g());
}
```

response json is in **response.res**

I use .net framework 3.5 and JSON.NET for parsing.

now how do I detect that in which json form is **res** and how use it ??

a response json example in form 1:

> {"needUserChoose":[{"type":"video/mp4","url":"http://youtube.com/?id=55","size":["1578978020","1.47
>   GB"],"video_id":"TmE_HSoDIUY","name":"End of Nations - Totalbiscuit
>   vs. Epic Meal Time - All 4 matches + RL
>   Interviews","id":55},{"type":"video/webm","url":"http://youtube.com/?id=56","size":["442230006","421.74
>   MB"],"video_id":"TmE_HSoDIUY","name":"End of Nations - Totalbiscuit
>   vs. Epic Meal Time - All 4 matches + RL
>   Interviews","id":56},{"type":"video/mp4","url":"http://youtube.com/?id=57","size":["383706129","365.93
>   MB"],"video_id":"TmE_HSoDIUY","name":"End of Nations - Totalbiscuit
>   vs. Epic Meal Time - All 4 matches + RL
>   Interviews","id":57},{"type":"video/x-flv","url":"http://youtube.com/?id=58","size":["191339943","182.48 MB"],"video_id":"TmE_HSoDIUY","name":"End of Nations - Totalbiscuit
>   vs. Epic Meal Time - All 4 matches + RL
>   Interviews","id":58},{"type":"video/3gpp","url":"http://youtube.com/?id=59","size":["126227794","120.38
>   MB"],"video_id":"TmE_HSoDIUY","name":"End of Nations - Totalbiscuit
>   vs. Epic Meal Time - All 4 matches + RL
>   Interviews","id":59},{"type":"video/3gpp","url":"http://youtube.com/?id=60","size":["44943692","42.86
>   MB"],"video_id":"TmE_HSoDIUY","name":"End of Nations - Totalbiscuit
>   vs. Epic Meal Time - All 4 matches + RL
>   Interviews","id":60}],"domain":"youtube.com"}

a response json example in form 2:

> {"received":true,"size":["44943692","42.86 MB"],"name":"End of Nations
>   - Totalbiscuit vs. Epic Meal Time - All 4 matches + RL Interviews.3gp","url":"https://r16---sn-4g57kn6s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?key=yt5&ip=2a01%3A4f8%3A192%3A43e1%3A%3A2&fexp=906956%2C945005%2C929209%2C931014%2C945807%2C913434%2C923341&upn=YA5ES2SkUTs&uinitcwndbps=403000&itag=17&requiressl=yes&mt=1400781466&mws=yes&mv=m&id=o-ADwpucaqaQakImjiu0_EJArWgPb8yJcrPSiOy8jm9uJC&ms=au&signature=2D17757B591677AD55FE64515EEDC04069D390.5D52B0A9A14A76775B3AF091F21CC21A6640263B&source=youtube&sparams=id%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cuinitcwndbps%2Cupn%2Cexpire&expire=1400803173&sver=3&ipbits=0","file":"http://www.dlbazi.com/multidl/downloads/End_of_Nations_-_Totalbiscuit_vs._Epic_Meal_Time_-_All_4_matches___RL_Interviews.3gp"}

**EDIT:** I have 2 question

1- we suppose that responsed string is in form 1. now must I first declare a **struct** and then convert response string to it ??

```
struct form1
{
    public String domain;
    public a[] needUserChoose;
}

struct a
{
    public int id;
    public String name, type, url, video_id;
    public String[] size;
}

void sendtoserverCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e2 = (RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)e;
    param response = (param)e2.Result;

    form1 res = (form1)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.res.ToString());
}
```

but this throws an **InvalidCastException** exeption!!

2- how do I detect that in which json form is responsed json string from server ?

Comment: I suggest you to add form id as a key , then at least you can know the response for which form

Comment: @Dibu please give me an code example!!

Comment: ok, first tell me have you written the server side api which is sending the response?

Comment: ok, then when you are sending request to the server then add form id in the querystring or header , then attach the form id in the response

Comment: is there not any other way ?? because changing server side code is very difficult. I edited my question. please read it again and give me a solution for question 1